# Is this an appropriate usage of "having said that"?

Tags: phrases

Here is my sentence -

We can always get a transfer to a different department in the office. Having said that one need a strong reason to do so.

Answer (score 3):

We can always get a transfer to a different department in the office. Having said that, one needs a strong reason to do so.

The use of the phrase

```
Having said that
```

is correct here, as it refers to the immediately preceding statement:
We can always ...

However there are a couple of grammatical corrections which are needed:

1. a comma after 'Having said that'.

Otherwise 'Having said that' would refer to the subsequent phrase 'one needs a strong reason etc.

2. The verb to need has to be in the third person singular - **needs**